# CFG and PDA for the grammar that has perfectly nested parentheses and brackets

Tags: c++, context-free-grammar, pushdown-automaton

I gotta make a CFG and PDA for the grammar that has perfectly nested parentheses and brackets.

```
S -> [S]
S -> (S)
S -> SS
S -> Epsilon
```

Not sure if this is correct, or how to make the PDA from it?

Comment: So what is your question? ... and how does this relate to C++?

Comment: @Dietmar Kühl: Two questions, the first on context-free-grammar, the second about C++ implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at [Spirit](http://boost-spirit.com/home/). It's really worth a *deep* visit.

Otherwise, your grammar it's so simple that a [recursive LL(1) parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser) should be easy to write.